# Can Kafka Mirror Maker failover between 2 Kafka clusters?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

When using MirrorMaker for a forwarding flow like A->B, B->C what are the
options for handling failure of B so that C could then mirror from A?

From what I can see MirrorMaker has no concept of failover so C cannot
failover to A.

An option could be having multiple MirrorMaker instances - one to mirror
from A and one to mirror from B - that could then be controlled by another
process depending on the availability of A or B.

Does Mirror Maker provide a solution for this scenario?